# Topbar dropdown heading style issue on Jobs page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-jobs

Found a little bug while browsing around, the headings in the topbar are larger than they are meant to be - I'm guessing some CSS overlap with `font-size`.

It is such a minor bug, I thought I would help out by drawing some free-hand circles to point it out.

[image: Styling conflict example]

It doesn't just affect the jobs detail page, it seems that all job pages are affected.

Tested in Firefox 48.0.1 and Chrome 52.0.2743.116

Comment: hey, thanks for reporting that. fix is waiting in repo for build. should be live within next couple hours.

Comment: If now fixed, @Paweł, don't forget to update the tag to [meta-tag:status-completed]! Either you or Turner might also want to post this new status as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).